# error Type 'Job' does not satisfy the constraint 'Document<any> / error Property 'save' does not exist on type

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose, nestjs

can you please tell me what else I can adjust here?

No matter what I do, it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance.

KR

```
npm run start:dev
```

> jobs-api@0.0.1 start:dev C:....\TypeScript\jobs-api
> nest start --watch
> [12:43:14 PM] Starting compilation in watch mode...

```
src/jobs/jobs.service.ts:8:70 - error TS2344: Type 'Job' does not satisfy the constraint 'Document<any>'.
  Type 'Job' is missing the following properties from type 'Document<any>': $ignore, $isDefault, $isDeleted, $isEmpty, and 45 more.
```

```
src/jobs/jobs.service.ts:8:70 - error TS2344: Type 'Job' does not satisfy the constraint 'Document<any>'.
  Type 'Job' is missing the following properties from type 'Document<any>': $ignore, $isDefault, $isDeleted, $isEmpty, and 45 more.

8     constructor(@InjectModel('Job') private readonly jobModel: Model<Job>) {}
                                                                       ~~~

src/jobs/jobs.service.ts:15:29 - error TS2339: Property 'save' does not exist on type 'Job'.

15         return await newJob.save();
                               ~~~~

[12:48:24 PM] Found 2 errors. Watching for file changes.
[12:48:46 PM] File change detected. Starting incremental compilation...
```

```
src/jobs/jobs.service.ts:8:70 - error TS2344: Type 'Job' does not satisfy the constraint 'Document<any>'.
  Type 'Job' is missing the following properties from type 'Document<any>': $ignore, $isDefault, $isDeleted, $isEmpty, and 45 more.
[12:52:37 PM] File change detected. Starting incremental compilation...

src/jobs/interfaces/job.interface.ts:2:30 - error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'mongoose'.
```

2 export interface Job extends mongoose.Document{
~~~~~~~~

```
src/jobs/interfaces/job.interface.ts:2:30 - error TS4022: 'extends' clause of exported interface 'Job' has or is using private name 'mongoose'.
[12:58:30 PM] File change detected. Starting incremental compilation...

src/jobs/jobs.service.ts:8:70 - error TS2344: Type 'Job' does not satisfy the constraint 'Document<any>'.
  Type 'Job' is missing the following properties from type 'Document<any>': $ignore, $isDefault, $isDeleted, $isEmpty, and 45 more.
[12:58:37 PM] Starting compilation in watch mode...

src/jobs/jobs.service.ts:8:70 - error TS2344: Type 'Job' does not satisfy the constraint 'Document<any>'.
  Type 'Job' is missing the following properties from type 'Document<any>': $ignore, $isDefault, $isDeleted, $isEmpty, and 45 more.

8     constructor(@InjectModel('Job') private readonly jobModel: Model<Job>) {}
                                                                       ~~~

src/jobs/jobs.service.ts:15:29 - error TS2339: Property 'save' does not exist on type 'Job'.

15         return await newJob.save();
                               ~~~~

[12:58:40 PM] Found 2 errors. Watching for file changes.
```

---

**jobs.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Job } from './interfaces/job.interface';
import { Model, Document } from 'mongoose';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';

@Injectable()
export class JobsService {
    constructor(@InjectModel('Job') private readonly jobModel: Model<Job>) {}

    async find(id: string): Promise<Job> {
        return await this.jobModel.findOne({ _id: id});
    }
    async create(job: Job): Promise<Job> {
        const newJob = new this.jobModel(job);
        return await newJob.save();
    }
    async update(id: string, job: Job): Promise<Job> {
        return await this.jobModel.findByIdAndUpdate(id, job, { new: true });
    }
    async delete(id: string): Promise<Job> {
        return await this.jobModel.findByIdAndRemove(id);
    }


}
```

---

**job.interface.ts**

```
import {  Document } from 'mongoose';
export interface Job extends Document{
    id?: string;
    title: string;
    salary: number; 
}
```

---

**package.json**

```
  "name": "jobs-api",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "private": true,
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "rimraf dist",
    "build": "nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "nest start",
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^7.5.1",
    "@nestjs/core": "^7.5.1",
    "@nestjs/mongoose": "^7.2.3",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^7.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.11.17",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^7.5.1",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^7.1.3",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^7.5.1",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.8",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.15",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.6",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.10",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.6.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.6.1",
    "eslint": "^7.12.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "7.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.4",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "prettier": "^2.1.2",
    "supertest": "^6.0.0",
    "ts-jest": "^26.4.3",
    "ts-loader": "^8.0.8",
    "ts-node": "^9.0.0",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^3.9.0",
    "typescript": "^4.0.5"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".*\\.spec\\.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.(t|j)s"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
}
```

**jobs.controller.ts**

```
import { Controller, Get, Post, Put, Delete, Param, Body } from '@nestjs/common';
import { JobsService } from './jobs.service';
import { JobDTO } from './dtos/job.dto';
import { Job } from './interfaces/job.interface';

@Controller('jobs')
export class JobsController {
    constructor (private readonly jobsService: JobsService) {}
    
    @Get(':id')
    find(@Param('id') id): Promise<Job> {
        return this.jobsService.find(id);
    }

    @Post()
    create(@Body() job: JobDTO): Promise<Job> {
        return this.jobsService.create(job);
    }

    @Put(':id')
    update(@Param('id') id, @Body() job: JobDTO): Promise<Job> {
        return this.jobsService.update(id, job);
    }

    @Delete(':id')
    delete(@Param('id') id): Promise<Job> {
        return this.jobsService.delete(id);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## First problem

Every interface of a schema must extend the Document interface.
Try this.

```js
import { Document } from 'mongoose';
export interface Job extends Document {
    id?: string;
    title: string;
    salary: number; 
}
```

If that doesn't work, please add your package.json to the question

## **Second problem:  Argument of type 'JobDTO' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Job'**

To solve this just set the DTO as the type of the params. The interface Job is for the model do not use as the param type of the function. Remember that if you wanna create some document the DTO must have the same properties, if you want to update a document you just need some properties.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Job } from './interfaces/job.interface';
import { Model, Document } from 'mongoose';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';

@Injectable()
export class JobsService {
    constructor(@InjectModel('Job') private readonly jobModel: Model<Job>) {}

    async find(id: string): Promise<Job> {
        return await this.jobModel.findOne({ _id: id});
    }
    async create(job: JobDTO): Promise<Job> { //JobDTO
        const newJob = new this.jobModel(job);
        return await newJob.save();
    }
    async update(id: string, job: JobDTO): Promise<Job> { //JobDTO
        return await this.jobModel.findByIdAndUpdate(id, job, { new: true });
    }
    async delete(id: string): Promise<Job> {
        return await this.jobModel.findByIdAndRemove(id);
    }


}
```

Btw, I recommend you to create a different DTO to update, something like this:

```js
export class JobDTO { //Your normal DTO
    title!: string;
    salary!: number; 
}

export class UpdateJobDTO extends Partial<JobDTO> {} //Your Update DTO
//The Partial type converts all the properties of JobDTO to optional
```

### Let me know if this solves your problem ;)

Comment: Now, new Problem: ```error TS2345: Argument of type 'JobDTO' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Job'.
  Type 'JobDTO' is missing the following properties from type 'Job': $ignore, $isDefault, $isDeleted, $isEmpty, and 45 more.

17         return this.jobsService.create(job);```

Comment: ```error TS2345: Argument of type 'JobDTO' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Job'.

22         return this.jobsService.update(id, job);```

Comment: Updated answer, check it.